# Bug report: account manually unsuspended

Tags: bug, chat, moderator-tools

Background: After a flag is carried out, chat users are barred from chatting for 30 minutes. However, a moderator can manually end such an automatic suspension.

Issue: Some time in the last few months, the manual moderator suspension reversal changed on the website when used via desktop browser. It no longer instantly ends the suspension, but changes the message to the following:

> your account has been manually unsuspended by a moderator and cannot chat for (original suspension remainder) minutes.

This is a low grade bug; the user can refresh the page and regains chat access. However, a user who doesn't know to refresh the page could just as easily overlook the message and believe the suspension is continuing to be carried out in full.